# mask NetCDF using shapefile and calculate average and anomaly for all polygons within the shapefile

Tags: python, mask, netcdf, shapefile

There are several tutorials ([example 1](https://www.guillaumedueymes.com/post/shapefiles_country/), [example 2](http://www.matteodefelice.name/post/aggregating-gridded-data/), [example 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354782/masking-netcdf-time-series-data-from-shapefile-using-python)) about masking NetCDF using shapefile and calculating average measures. However, I was confused with those workflows about masking NetCDF and extracting measures such as average, and those tutorials did not include extract anomaly (for example, the difference between temperature in 2019 and a baseline average temperature).

I make an example here. I have downloaded monthly temperature ([download temperature file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o-VYs4WsySestmKYjIZXdo2uCAmuPBad/view?usp=sharing)) from 2000 to 2019 and the state-level US shapefile ([download shapefile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G2nVUGWH_ugFbs4BXBzo-oqSkgYP6YCC/view?usp=sharing)). I want to get the state-level average temperature based on the monthly average temperature from 2000 to 2019 and the temperature anomaly of year 2019 relative to baseline temperature from 2000 to 2010. Specifically, the final dataframe looks as follow:

| state | avg_temp | anom_temp2019 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AL | xx | xx |
| AR | xx | xx |
| ... | ... | ... |
| WY | xx | xx |

```
# Load libraries
%matplotlib inline

import regionmask
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read shapefile
us = gpd.read_file('./shp/state_cus.shp')

# Read gridded data
ds = xr.open_mfdataset('./temp/monthly_mean_t2m_*.nc')
......
```

I really appreciate your help that providing an explicit workflow that could do the above task. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using regionmask. I don't use your files but the xarray tutorial data and [naturalearth](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/) data for the US states.

```py
import numpy as np
import regionmask
import xarray as xr

# load polygons of US states
us_states_50 = regionmask.defined_regions.natural_earth.us_states_50

# load an example dataset
air = xr.tutorial.load_dataset("air_temperature")

# turn into monthly time resolution
air = air.resample(time="M").mean()

# create a mask
mask3D = us_states_50.mask_3D(air)

# latitude weights
wgt = np.cos(np.deg2rad(air.lat))

# calculate regional averages
reg_ave = air.weighted(mask3D * wgt).mean(("lat", "lon"))

# calculate the average temperature (over 2013-2014)
avg_temp = reg_ave.sel(time=slice("2013", "2014")).mean("time")

# calculate the anomaly (w.r.t. 2013-2014)
reg_ave_anom = reg_ave - avg_temp

# select a single timestep (January 2013)
reg_ave_anom_ts = reg_ave_anom.sel(time="2013-01")

# remove the time dimension
reg_ave_anom_ts = reg_ave_anom_ts.squeeze(drop=True)

# convert to a pandas dataframe so it's in tabular form
df = reg_ave_anom_ts.air.to_dataframe()

# set the state codes as index
df = df.set_index("abbrevs")

# remove other columns
df = df.drop(columns="names")
```

You can find info how to use your own shapefile on the [regionmask docs](https://regionmask.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) ([Working with geopandas](https://regionmask.readthedocs.io/en/stable/notebooks/geopandas.html)).

disclaimer: I am the main author of regionmask.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was not quite clear about weighting, why should we use weight, and why to use latitude-based weight, can we use longitude-based weight, and if yes, what are the difference between lat-based and lon-based weight?

Comment: It depends on the grid you are using. Gridcells become smaller as you move towards the pole. On a regular lat-lon grid they scale with the cosine of lat, for non-regualr grids it's different. The longituges on the other hand are the same length everywhere. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I got another question. The us_states_50 has 51 regions (or, maybe I can call it states), however, after masking, the mask3D has only 43 regions (region 6, 7, 8, 11, 20, 30, 39 and 49 are missing), why there are several regions missing?

Comment: Regions that do not contain any points are removed (e.g. Hawai). You can keep these regions by setting `mask3D = us_states_50.mask_3D(air, drop=False)`. In `df` they will turn up as `NaN` values.

Comment: Thanks. A further question related to this. To me, an NC file consists of grid cells (represented by lat-lon pairs) with every cell storing several values (e.g., temperature, precipitation, etc.). That means every region should have some cells fall into it, right? How come some regions contain no cells (or points)? Maybe the regions are too small?

Comment: Currently every gridpoint can be part of one or zero regions. If a gridpoint is part of a region is determined by it's center point (i.e. the lat and lon coords). Put simply it is `region.contains(lon, lat)`. So if a region contains no cells that can mean the region is too small (the gridpoints too far apart) or the region is outside of the bounds of gridpoints (e.g.  if the model is not global).

Comment: Understood, thanks for the clarification.